# Shuffle elements of an array

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I am new to Java and  trying to use the `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle elements of my ArrayList. Can anybody help?

```
public class tracklist {

    ArrayList<File> tracklist = new ArrayList<File>();
    String trackListName;

    public static void shuffle(List<?> tracklist, Random rnd) {
        tracklist.shuffle();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class TestDrive {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        //test basic MP3 player
        Mp3Player mp = new Mp3Player();
        File myMusicFile = new File("u:\\02.wav");
        mp.play(myMusicFile);

        //test advanced MP3 player
        Mp3Advance adv = new Mp3Advance();

        //Populate your favs play list or change its name
        tracklist favs = new tracklist();
        favs.addSong(new File("u:\\02.wav"));
        favs.addSong(new File("u:\\03.wav"));

        adv.playTracklist(favs);
        System.out.println("Now Playing:" + favs + "playlist");

        //shuffle play list
        Collections.shuffle(favs);
        System.out.println("Now playing" + favs + "playlist in shuffle");
    }
}
```

I have uploaded both my test drive and tracklist code to help. I think that I'm just trying to shuffle the wrong object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `List` doesn't have shuffle method and `trackList` is not a valid `Collection` object

Comment: What is the problem?
Did you try multiple time, because you have many chance to find the same order after shuffle a collection of two items.
You should add some more tracks and test again.

Answer (score 4):

In your `trackList` class you will be required to change the `shuffle` method

From

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> tracklist,Random rnd){
    tracklist.shuffle();
}
```

to (something like)

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> tracklist,Random rnd){
    Collections.shuffle(tracklist, rnd);
}
```

Now, personally, I wouldn't bother making the method static and simple provide a `shuffle` method that shuffles the internal list...

```
public void shuffle(){
    Collections.shuffle(tracklist);
}
```

So you could just do something more like...

```
tracklist favs = new tracklist();
// Add tracks, do other stuff...
favs.shuffle();
```

ps- I would also suggest you familiarise yourself with the [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) ;)

**Updated**

I'd recommend that you `TrackList` class should look more like...

```
public class TrackList {

    private ArrayList<File> tracklist = new ArrayList<File>();
    private String trackListName;

    public void addSong(File file) {
        tracklist.add(file);
    }

    public void removeSong(File file) {
        tracklist.remove(file);
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(tracklist);
    }

    // Additional functionality as required...
}
```

Comment: //new shuffle tracklis
            tracklist newfavs = new tracklist ();
            //add tracks ecta here
            favs.addSong(new File("u:\\04.wav"));
            favs.addSong(new File("u:\\05.wav"));
            newfavs.shuffle();
            
            adv.playTracklist(newfavs);
            System.out.println("Now Playing:" +newfavs + "playlist");
        }
    }

Comment: method shuffle in class tracklist cannot be applied to given types;
  required: List<?>,Random
  found: no arguments

Comment: And your shuffle method looks like the one I suggest? (ie no parameters, no `static` reference...)

Comment: The error states that the `tracklist.shuffle()` method does not exist and it is expected two parameters, `List` and `Random`, so either your method is signature is wrong or you're referencing the wrong class.  See updates

Comment: It cant find the main test drive class. Great. Thankyou very much>>>> and i will take your recommendation on the oracle pdf. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep object oriented:

```
public class TrackList extends ArrayList<File>
{
    public void addSong(File track)
    {
        add(track);
    }

    public void shuffle()
    {
        Collections.shuffle(this);
    }
}
```

And then

```
TrackList tracks = new TrackList();
tracks.addSong(new File("mp3_01.mp3"));
tracks.addSong(new File("mp3_2.mp3"));
tracks.shuffle();
```